# Why is the before pseudo-selector not working properly unless a class is assigned?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

**HTML**

```
<label>
  <Input type="checkbox"/>
  <span class="check-label">Remember me</span>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="checkbox"] + .check-label:before {
  content: "before";
}
```

So this css works as expected, when I use a class, but when I do something like this:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label > span:before {
  content: "before";
}
```

the before content doesn't appear. I don't like to use a bunch of classes and IDs unless I have to, so how come for this particular case I'm forced to do so?

Comment: `input[type="checkbox"] + label` asks for a label directly after a checkbox, which is not what you have. Maybe you meant `label > input[type="checkbox"] + span:before`. Also, classes are good.

Comment: So what happens is CSS sees `+ label` instead of `+ label....`? So I have to use a class to get around that?

Comment: No. `a + b` means “find a `b` that’s directly after its sibling `a`”. Your `<label>` and `<input>` are parent and child, not siblings.

Comment: But isn't `label > span` a sibling of `<input>`?

Comment: There’s no precedence, it’s just left to right (or right to left). `a + b > c` means a `c` that’s a child of a `b` that’s after an `a`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with isherwood, but I think what you're actually looking for is this:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  content: "before";
}
```